# How to get a trigger on the user who approved the pull request?

Tags: github-actions

We use this action:

```
name: _On PR review
on:
  pull_request_review:
    types: [submitted]

jobs:
  approved:
    runs-on: [self-hosted]
    steps:
      - name: Send approved message to tg
        if: github.event.review.state == 'approved'
        with:
          silent_mode: "false"
          chat_id: ${{ secrets.PROJECT_CHAT_ID }}
          tg_url: ${{ secrets.TG_URL }}
          message: |
            Approved : ${{ github.event ???????????? }}
```

How to get the username of the user who checked the pull request and approved?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is a sender object that triggers the event.

```
${{ github.event.sender.login }}
```